# Python stops printing to output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that prints to an output file

```
def drawfile(m):
    findcovers(m)
    i = 1
    for x in m.intervalm:
        print("===="+str(i)+"====", file = output)
        print(configtostr(x.config), file = output)
        print("covered by:" + listtostr(x.parents,"+"), file = output)
        print("covers:" + listtostr(x.children,"-"), file = output)
        drawf(x)
        i = i + 1
```

I've run the same script twice and both times the output file stops after printing `print(configtostr(x.config), file = output)` without printing the next line `print("covered by:" + listtostr(x.parents,"+"), file = output)`, both times at the same entry in `m.intervalm`.

For reference

```
def listtostr(l,string=" "):
    result = string
    for x in l:
        result += (str(x) + string)
    return result
```

is a pretty simple function that I don't think is looping infinitely. The script does continue to compute several more long computations after printing this file, so I looked into print buffering. But I don't think this is happening since it's been 48 hours and the output file is still not updated, and there is a lot more that should be printing. I know from what has already been printed that the later entries of `m.intervalm` have been computed. Python hasn't given me any errors either.

I'm pretty stuck, and would appreciate any insight/help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `outfile` and is it initialized? Where is it closed?

Comment: I have `output = open("output.txt", "w")`. I don't close it. I should say that I have run this script on smaller examples (which still take a day to compute), and they give me the full output file.

Comment: The functionality of `listtostr(x.parents,"+")` is built-in: `'+'.join(x.parents)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with Python so I'm sure I'm rewriting a lot of things. In any case, I'm not convinced that's where my script is going wrong.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  Only if x.parents is already strings.  And his seems to want the joiner at the end, too.

Comment: If you do not close (or flush) an open file, the content is not guaranteed to show up when you open the file in another program.

Comment: This is going to be silly, but worth checking.  You're positive that `configtostr` (or something it calls) doesn't modify the variable `output`?  That's really the only explanation that I can come up with.

Comment: I'm very sure `configtostr` doesn't modify `output`. I know this isn't really proof that it doesn't, but my output only stops printing after 7000+ entries from `m.intervalm`. In my other examples I've computed, I've been able to print out 19000 entries without any problem.

Comment: I'll try running this again with closing the file. I've run this script a lot of other times with no problems though... I'm curious now why it's important to close files.